# Tilemap array of unknown size

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2012, sfml

I want the users to pick there map size so I do not know the size of the map at run time. I have been looking around how I can implement this with little success. Closest to something that is working is with the vector variant but while it runs it still does not work properly.

I want a 3 dimensional array so in my header i declare the tilemap like this.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>> tileMap;
```

and test it in the class like this:

```
World::World(int width, int height, int depth)
{
tileMap.resize(width);
tileMap[0].resize(height);
tileMap[0][0].resize(depth);

tileMap.resize(width);

for (int i = 0;i<width;i++)
{
    tileMap[i].resize(height);
}



for (int y = 0; y < height;y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        tileMap[x,y].resize(depth);
    }
}

std::cout << sizeof tileMap / sizeof tileMap[0][0][0] << std::endl;

}
```

I am aware that not all the dimensions of the array are resized properly but the final line just outputs "0".

Is there i better way to create my tilemap of unknown size? I need a lot of sizes like 64*64, 256*256, 64*1024, etc (the z levels will be determined after generating the level). so creating an array for each size seems inefficient. But maybe there is a better way of declaring my array or i am doing something wrong somewhere.

Comment: `sizeof` *really* doesn't do what you think... also, `operator[]()` only ever takes *one* argument; you cannot say `tileMap[x,y]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `tileMap.size() * tileMap[0].size() * tileMap[0][0].size()` to get the number of tiles.

Comment: Why does sizeof not work the way it should (it always worked for me with normal arrays and independent of the type it holds). I flag this as the answer but your comment helped out too, i knew that already but i fiddled around with this for hours and the mind loses track eventually :D. I hope i can finally start filling this array up and work with it :D, thanks!.

Comment: @MennoGouw: `sizeof` gives you the size of the static type. For a vector, that's just like a struct of three pointers. The *content* of the vector is dynamically allocated and not statically knowable.